# Powershell Try/Catch not executing when invoked from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, try-catch

1. List item
2. $LOGFILE="c:\log2\crush1.txt"

   ```
   function log
   {
       write-host $($args[0])
       echo $($args[0]) >> $LOGFILE
   }

   log "Main Before TRY"
   try {
       log "Inside TRY"
   }
   catch {
       log "Inside CATCH"
   }   

   log "Main After TRY"

   return "Powershell script completed successfully"
   ```

   Here is my C# code:

   namespace HostSamples {
       using System;
       using System.Management.Automation;  // Windows PowerShell namespace.
       using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
       using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
       using System.IO;
       using System.Text;

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// </summary>
   internal class HostPS1
   {
       private static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

           ps.AddScript(LoadScript(@"c:\\temp\\crush1.ps1"));
           Console.WriteLine("Starting");

           foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
           {
               Console.WriteLine(result);
           }
           Console.WriteLine("Finished");
           Console.ReadLine();
       }

       static string LoadScript(string filename)
       {
           try
           {
               using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
               {

                   // use a string builder to get all our lines from the file 
                   StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder();

                   // string to hold the current line 
                   string curLine;

                   while ((curLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                   {
                       fileContents.Append(curLine + "\n");
                   }

                   return fileContents.ToString();
               }
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               string errorText = "The file could not be read:";
               errorText += e.Message + "\n";
               return errorText;
           }

       }

   } // End HostPs1. }
   ```

Comment: When executed via powershell, the output contains "Inside Try".  When executed from C# the output only displays "Main Before TRY" and "Main After TRY"

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  For some reason having a write-host call inside the log function caused the try to trigger an exception.  The catch also called the log function, so it did not write anything to the output file.  The output file traces made it look like the try-catch had been skipped entirely.

I cannot explain why the try-catch would complain about a write-host call, but the rest of the script does not.  Possibly a scope issue.

Once I commented out the write-host statement in the log function, everything ran normally.